# Docker PostgreSQL: cannot connect to the server on Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I run on Windows 10

```
docker run -it --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p5401:5432 postgres:12.3-alpine
```

it works fine. I can connect to PostgreSQL, create database etc, all is ok.

But when I run the same docker on my 2nd machine Windows 7 I receive

> Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
>   the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5401?

What may be the reason? what to check?

### That is pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host all all ::1/128 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local replication all trust
host replication all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
host replication all ::1/128 trust
host all all all md5
```

Comment: could you please add the pg_hba.conf to your question?

Comment: Yes, I can add it, btw it is the same on w10 (works fine) and w7(cannot connect). See the start message.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the possible issues are:

1) The server has not actually been started in the Docker server.

Verify server is running.

2) Port 5401 is not visible to the client that is trying to connect.

Ping the port. Could be a firewall issue.

Comment: I have switched off FW on Windows host OS.

Comment: Telnet localhost 5401 - cannot connect. But it seems the same reason. The PG is started because I see how it executes init scripts on the Docker container start: it creates db, tables. I see it in the Docker container log when it is active

Comment: Is the port actually on localhost or on IP for the container?

Comment: As I wrote: I run the docker ">docker run -it --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p5401:5432 postgres:12.3-alpine" i.e.  docker's 5432 -> hosts 5401

Comment: The same container wokrs fine on Windows 10, I can connect to the db etc, but it starts on WIndows 7 and I cannot connect to  PG . It is the same container in docker hub.

Comment: The error message is telling you it can't find that port and that happens for the reasons I stated above. Obviously there is something different about your Windows 7 setup. I would start with netstat to see what the host is seeing. Also the message indicates that it is looking for Ipv6 localhost(::1), so could that be an issue?